# How to get UserName from FirebaseUser using authentication Uid in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I registered a user by using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` and login using `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` methods. Now when I login a user I need to get the username, mobile, that are stored in the user node. I could get the UId for each user, by using this how it possible to get the mentioned information in android?

Comment: you can use user id to fetch user node.!

Comment: Please post your Database structure so we can help you.

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi In user node there is only pushed key, not the UId.

Comment: kindly post your database structure.!

Comment: User-> Email , Mobile, Password, Name, UserId.

Comment: I just used                                                                               FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
String UId = currentUser.getUid();                                               String UName = currentUser.getDisplayName();   Here I could get exact UId, but UName shows null...

Comment: @PeterHaddad But I want to take this "mName" using this UId .

Comment: @Proversion have a look at my updated answer.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

all you have to do is use `UserProfileChangeRequest`

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    // Sign in success
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                        .setDisplayName(mName).build();

                    user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
             }
         }
     });


                }
    });
```

Then, to retrieve it, use this wherever required,

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Name, email address etc
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();
}
```

or you can create your own custom node.!

```
 String currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();

//save user node after successful signup.
      mFirebaseInstance.getReference("user").child(scurrentuser ).setValue(parameters);



    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(currentuser );
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


      for(DataSnapshot userSnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            User user = userSnapShot.getValue(User.class);
        }
        }
```

Comment: I just used user.getDisplayName() method, but it shows null value.

Comment: check are you getting success in 
user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener

Comment: well, It is worked!! one more thing now how to set multiple values like phone number?